# Why the majority of serious machine learners are from the computer vision society?

Tags: machine-learning

I have noticed that most individuals who want to specialize in machine learning tend to go into computer vision labs. I was always curious about why computer vision in particular. My confusion was basically because I find computer vision quit a boring task. Classifying images as cats or dogs or numbers is not interesting at all for me. Maybe for others. But to some extent I don't believe that those people go there because they are really passionate about computer vision in particular.

Also I noticed that most universities have only 'computer vision' labs. I always wondered why not to call them "machine learning" labs.

My question:

- Do people choose to go with computer vision because it's the most challenging machine learning task such that if you can solve it then you can solve any problem, or is it something else?

Edit:

I'm not sure how to reword this question to make it better. If someone has an idea, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for speculation about motives.

Comment: One way to re-frame the question would be to ask "Why is there so much interest in machine vision?" without assuming that machine vision specialists are "more serious," or calling the field "boring." Make your question about *facts*, not your feelings.

Comment: It's where the money is: self-driving cars, security (facial recognition instead of IDs and credit cards), military (robot soldiers, self-guiding weapons), retail (recognizing customers visiting stores) etc.

Answer (score 9):

I think your question has a false premise. While computer vision is an interesting problem with many challenging facets, I can name half-a-dozen obscure fields which have equally -- or even more -- "serious" ML practitioners. These include fields like e-discovery, automated risk assessment, and financial algorithms. And I think you're placing too much emphasis on what you yourself find interesting -- while you don't like sorting cats from dogs, some people like working on problems where there are obvious correct and incorrect answers. Most of the problems I work on are much less well-defined, and that can be frustrating.

One important consideration is that computer vision likely has considerable private and public funding behind it for various reasons (commercialization of the technology for things like like self-driving cars, or military applications). Your university might be better able to shed light on their labs' naming conventions, but my guess is that they have funding for a computer vision lab for whatever reason. In turn, this implies that you could answer this question by checking out who is underwriting the grants to machine vision specialists. I'll bet you a dollar that a substantial number in the US receive funding from the Office of Naval Research, DARPA, or similar organizations.

Another reason is that the basic science of machine vision is neither inherently proprietary nor confidential. An e-discovery corpus is almost always under protective order, and financial algorithms are the "secret sauce" of a algorithmic trading enterprise, so neither is likely to be discussed openly.